# Um outro significado de "x" ou "versus"?

Tags: significado, preposições, abreviações

Depois de ver "x" usado na televisão para eventos de desporto, por exemplo "Brasil x Alemanha", fiquei com a ideia que é abreviação para "versus" neste contexto.

Fiz uma pesquisa no SO.PT sobre o uso de "x", e encontrei um uso que não estou a entender. Na maioria dos casos entendei perfeitamente, porque "x" foi usado para significar:

- uma variável
- um número não especificado
- mesmo "versus" no significado que encontrei em varios dicionários, por exemplo [no Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/versus):

> prep. Em oposição a; contra

Mas de vez em quando encontrei outro uso desta abreviação, onde parece significar outras coisas como "e", "com", "usando", "no contexto de" ou "perante": *(ênfase minha)*

- > [Javascript **x** Ajax **x** html **x** jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/84072/8244)
  >
  > Estou tentando desenvolver um aplicativo com phonegap **x** html **x** jquery **x** javascript **e** Ajax…
- > [DelphiXE5 **X** Permissão Administrador](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33008/8244)
  >
  > Preciso rodar um programa em Delphi **como** Administrador…
- > [StringReplace **x** Array](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33253/8244)
  >
  > Preciso fazer com que o StringReplace procure qualquer nome **que esteja dentro do** array e substitua.

Também encontrei um uso assim de "vs":

- > [Sobre o atributo booleano defer e async **vs** otimização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/46459/8244)
  >
  > O uso de `async` e `defer` **para** otimização é um bom assunto a tocarmos quando queremos páginas carregadas de forma mais rápida e também sem problemas de bloqueamento.

Pesquisei em três dicionários, mas não encontrei um significado de "versus" que me parece significar "no contexto de" nem "e". Também ainda não encontrei uma definição para a abreviação "x". Alguém pode me explicar estes significados?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resposta por intuição:

Provavelmente o símbolo correto nessa situação seria, não a letra “xis” mas o sinal de multiplicação, ×. Penso que a leitura correta seja “com”: «HTML × Javascript» significa efetivamente «HTML com Javascript».

O sinal de multiplicação quererá dizer que cada um dos elementos indicados é um *fator* que entra na solução.

Comment: Esqueci completamente dessa possibilidade! Parece provável sim.

Comment: @DanGetz Também me parece ser esta a explicação mais provável. Não percebo de computação, mas creio que aqui **x** significa interação. **x** é usado com esse significado em testes estatísticos na literatura em inglês (Googla por exemplo *sex x age*).

Comment: Indo na linha da acepção estatística, ***x*** também pode ser entendido tacitamente como *cruzado com* (no mesmo sentido que o cruzamento entre dois fatores -- a interação -- em um desenho experimental fatorial), o que tornaria as expressões acima mais razoáveis.

Comment: esse X não significaria oposição?

Comment: @AndréLyra nestas frases acho que oposição não faria sentido, visto que tem dois ou mais elementos que trabalham juntos. Acho que só podia significar oposição se for um caso de expressar ironia…

Comment: oposição no sentido de um contra o outro

Comment: @AndréLyra *contra* tem sentido de *junto com*?

Comment: O sinal de multiplicação em lógica significa 'E' e o de soma significa 'OU', assim como na informática, mas o 'X' significa uma coisa em oposição a outra coisa, um comparativo.

Answer (score -1):

No Brasil, a palavra "versus" vem de algo contrário. Mas também é comum, devido sua forma de falar, ser comparada por "vezes", termo utilizado para multiplicação. Aí é uma das explicações para o "x" da multiplicação.
A outra explicação é não é exatamente "Brasil vezes Alemanha", mas sim, já um simbolismo em relação a gols efetuados durante o jogo: "Brasil 0 x 4 Alemanha". Seria uma abreviação e a mais pertinente seria o "X". Algo como 0 "a" 4. E aqui, geralmente - não sei dizer ainda se é geral - no canto onde fica o resultado parcial/final do jogo, o time que aparece "em cima" - não aparece "lado a lado" e sim "em cima e embaixo" - é o mandante do jogo, ou seja, é no campo/cidade dele onde está ocorrendo o jogo.